# What are the safety measures that i need to do after giving a freelance developer access to my magento2 backend credential and FTP credential?

Tags: ftp, magento2

I gave a freelance developer the magento2 backend credential and FTP credential to outsource the development of a custom magento2 module. What are the safety measures that i need to do aside from changing the passwords of magento2 backend and FTP to prevent from being hacked in the future?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that You are giving an admin panel with new user and password for your freelancer's to work. That you can done from magento2 admin panel itself. If you are not done so, if you were gave admin master user name and password you should need to change the password of your admin by using following query.

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxYourNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';
```

For more to know about reset password go to the [link](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-reset-admin-password-magento-2.html)

And definitely you have to change the FTP Credential too from your server back end.

The most taking care you can prohibit the admin login with IP address.

Hope these things are helpful to you.

Comment: Hi, can i change it using the admin panel interface instead of command line? please refer to the above screenshot.

Comment: Yep, You can do through admin panel itself. If you forgot the password or any kind of missing password You can use that update query too.